# Transforming DataTable structure - Using column names as values

Tags: r

I have a datatable formatted as follows:

```
Name            A1    A2    A3     A4
Object 1         1     0     1      0
Object 2         1     0     0      0
Object 3         0     1     0      1
```

What i'm trying to accomplish:

```
Name            Skill LeveL Skill Level Skill Level Skill Level 
Object 1           A1    1    A2     0     A3    1    A4     0
Object 2           A1    1    A2     0     A3    0    A4     0
Object 3           A1    0    A2     1     A3    0    A4     1
```

In R, what would be the best way to accomplish this? I'm aware of the fact that R cannot handle duplicate column names. To prevent this, 'Skill1, Level1 - Skill2, Level2') could work fine aswell as column names. My source datatable has a dynamic range of column names (So depending on the subset it contain between 2 and 40ish column names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
ll <- lapply(2:ncol(df), function(x) data.frame(Skill = names(df[x]), Level = df[, x]))
cbind(Name = df[, 1], do.call('cbind', ll))
```